# SQL query for the following tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to get the following results

Expecting the result are in the following table

```
HouseName   Address        CurrentResident
------------------------------------------
A           1 Market St    Smith
B           2 Market St    Einstein
X           3 Market St    [Vacant]
D           4 Market St    [Vacant]
```

Please help

The SQL query for the tables

```
CREATE TABLE House 
( 
     HouseName Varchar(1), 
     Address Varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Events 
(
    Id Integer, 
    HouseName Varchar(1), 
    EventName Varchar(255), 
    Date Date, 
    Family Varchar(255)
);

INSERT House VALUES('A', '1 Market St');
INSERT House VALUES('B', '2 Market St');
INSERT House VALUES('X', '3 Market St');
INSERT House VALUES('D', '4 Market St');

INSERT Events VALUES(1,'A','MoveIn','2005-01-31','Smith');
INSERT Events VALUES(2,'A','Remodel','2005-03-31','Smith');
INSERT Events VALUES(3,'A','Remodel','2008-03-31','Smith');
INSERT Events VALUES(4,'A','CleanUp','2008-05-31','Smith');
INSERT Events VALUES(5,'B','MoveIn','2005-01-31','Newton');
INSERT Events VALUES(6,'B','MoveOut','2008-05-01','Newton');
INSERT Events VALUES(7,'B','MoveIn','2008-12-01','Einstein');
INSERT Events VALUES(8,'D','MoveIn','2007-08-31','Soo');
INSERT Events VALUES(9,'D','MoveOut','2010-08-13','Soo');
```

The two resulting tables are as follows

```
HouseName   Address
    A   1 Market St
    B   2 Market St
    X   3 Market St
    D   4 Market St
```

Events

```
   Id   HouseName   EventName   Date    Family
    1   A             MoveIn    2005-01-31  Smith
    2   A            Remodel    2005-03-31  Smith
    3   A            Remodel    2008-03-31  Smith
    4   A            CleanUp    2008-05-31  Smith
    5   B             MoveIn    2005-01-31  Newton
    6   B            MoveOut    2008-05-01  Newton
    7   B             MoveIn    2008-12-01  Einstein
    8   D             MoveIn    2007-08-31  Musk
    9   D             MoveOut   2010-08-13  Musk
```

So for house d there is a move in and a move out but no recorded movein after that so it should show vacant

my code

```
SELECT HouseName, Address, currentresident  
FROM (SELECT h.*, COALESCE(e.Family, 'Vacant') AS currentresident, 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY h.HouseName ORDER BY e.Date desc) AS rn       
       FROM House AS h left JOIN Events AS e ON h.HouseName=e.HouseName) 
AS t     WHERE t.rn=1
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Tried left join and also using temp tables not getting the answer required

Comment: Nice job including the data set up in your question, and thank you. But we're here to help you with your code, not write it for you. What have you tried, and where are you running into trouble?

Comment: There are so many unknowns here. Why is `D` vacant when there is event associated with it? Do you want to show only latest events? Please add more context and your query

Comment: Put your code in the question (press the edit button), **not** in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to try on your larger database.

```
SELECT HouseName, Address, currentresident  
FROM (SELECT h.*,
        Case When e.EventName = 'MoveOut' Then 'Vacant' 
             Else COALESCE(e.Family, 'Vacant') End AS currentresident, 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY h.HouseName ORDER BY e.Date desc) AS rn       
       FROM xyzHouse AS h left JOIN xyzEvents AS e ON h.HouseName=e.HouseName) 
AS t     WHERE t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HouseName, Address, currentresident  
FROM (SELECT h.*, COALESCE(case when e.EventName='MoveOut' then null else e.Family end, 'Vacant') AS currentresident, 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY h.HouseName ORDER BY e.Date desc) AS rn       
       FROM House AS h left JOIN Events AS e ON h.HouseName=e.HouseName) 
AS t     WHERE t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select H.HouseName, H.Address, 
Case When ISNULL(e.EventName,'MoveOut')='MoveOut' then'[Vacant]'
      Else e.Family end as CurrentResident 
from House h
left join Events e on e.id = 
  (
      select max(e2.id) from events e2 
      where e2.housename = h.housename and e2.EventName in ('MoveIn','MoveOut')
  )
```